# JQGrid: Slow while saving row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Can anyone tell why it is taking long time when I try to save all selected rows

```
for (var i=0, il = selectedRows.length; i < il; i++) {
        var selectedRow = selectedRows[i];
        $("#myGrid").jqGrid('saveRow', selectedRow, false, 'clientArray');
}
```

FYI: I am using all same libraries as it is used [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarMultilpe1__48.htm)

Comment: The demo, which you included in the question, don't contains `saveRow`. What you do? Why *multiple* rows are edited in your case? How many rows you edit? How many columns and rows in the grid? You wrote about "long time". It would be more interesting to write how many milliseconds takes the saving of ... rows in your case. In any way the current question is unclear.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks Oleg for reply so quickly when I under fire now. yes that example does not have saveRow. But I am using same libraries only. So here what I am trying to do is to get data for all SELECTED rows. So I have to call var rowData = $("#preReviewSearchResultGridTable").jqGrid("getLocalRow", selectedRow);
     var data = JSON.stringify(rowData);  Now I am not getting editted data. So I must have call saverow for all selected rows, then only I am getting the JSON data. That saveRow for 200 records with 6 editable cloumns is taking around 5 minutes.

Comment: I wrote you before that editing of multiple rows is bad idea. Why you edit 200 rows? It's much more as one can display on the screen. You should understand that saving the data consist on *separate* modification of 200*6 elements. On modification of one cell the web browser have to recalculate position (reflow) of *all elements* existing on the page (see [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow)). The page with a grid with 1200 cells have much more as 1200 DOM elements. On one call of `saveRow` the web browser do 6 reflows of all thousand elements and you repeat it 200 times.

Comment: @Oleg: I agree with you. At this point of time, I am not in a position of changing the design provided by end user. Looking for a quick workaround now to get rid of this problem. May be later we can propose a new design.

Comment: @Oleg: Is there a way to Save entire grid, instead of saving each row by using saveRow.

Comment: You can **read** the whole information from all `<input>`, `<select>` and other editing elements which you have in the grid. It should work very quickly. Then you can send the information to the server if it's required. You can recreate the grid with new data. Recreating will be quickly too.

Comment: It's [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.4/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L248-L325), where [the part](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.4/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L248-L252) is the mostly important. In general two methods `$.jgrid.enumEditableCells` and `$.jgrid.getEditedValue` will do 90% of all what you need.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks a lot. Iterating through all edited rows with input, select IDs and get value, helped. Thanks a lot. But still struggling with Multiselect checkbox. When select mutli-select checkbox to select all rows, then again it takes 30 seconds to check all checkboxes and select all rows

Comment: It seems that you hold too many elements (for example rows) on the HTML page **without** local paging of data. It'a a wrong way especially if you need *to change* many elements at once. I strictly recommend you to use local paging of data. It will dramatically improve the performance of the grid.  Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm), which displays 5000 rows or [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm), which displays 40000 rows. Test sorting, paging and filtering of data.

Comment: Compare with [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-1000-1000-free-jqgrid.htm), which displays 1000 rows or even [one more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-400-400-free-jqgrid.htm) with only 400 rows. Try to sort the grids and compare with the performance of grids with 5000 or 40000 rows, but with local paging. You will see the difference. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/multiPageSelection.htm) shows `multiPageSelection: true` option. You can test "Select all" on the grid with local paging and the option to see the results.

Comment: @Oleg: I saw your example. It looks like there is nothing special done there. I am also not doing anything special. When you are saying "hold too many elements", does that mean too many too many rows and columns? fyi: I have around 350 rows and 15 columns. Any idea how I can improve the performance?

Comment: You should post **the JavaScript code**, which you use. Do you use the pager? Which value have `datatype`, `rowNum`, `loadonce`, ... ? The best would be if you create the demo, which reproduce the problem which you have. We spend just our time posting comments without to see the JavaScript code.

Comment: @Oleg: I can put the js code. But because of sensitive data, I can't, But if you tell which part of code, I can put that. Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe that the JavaScript code is sensitive. About the data: you can replace all strings with dummy strings. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm), which generates some test string data.